# how do you delete a language in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set the validator for plpgsql by deleting and then creating the plpgsql language with additional parameters. Postgres, however, doesn't seem to have the option of deleting a language...

```
db=# DELETE TRUSTED PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
db-# HANDLER plpgsql_call_handler
db-# VALIDATOR plpgsql_validator;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRUSTED"
LINE 1: DELETE TRUSTED PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: Postgresql has `DROP LANGUAGE`. [`Manual`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droplanguage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to CREATE OR REPLACE as follows...

```
db=# CREATE OR REPLACE TRUSTED PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
db-# HANDLER plpgsql_call_handler
db-# VALIDATOR plpgsql_validator;
NOTICE:  using pg_pltemplate information instead of CREATE LANGUAGE parameters
CREATE LANGUAGE
```